# Simple Chained Select Menu bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple jQuery select menu that displays content depending on selection.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/665yvqec/) & my code is below.

**Bug#1**: When I initially select `US`, the `State` dropdown doesn't appear. I have to select `UK` first, then `US` before this kicks in. Why?

**Bug#2**: Right now, I'm using: 
`if(jQuery('#statecat').val()=="ak")
 jQuery('.ak').show();
});` - is there a more efficient way to do this, so I don't have to do this for all 50 states?

**Bug#3**: When I go from `Alaska` back to `Choose a State...`, the `US` results are blank. Why?

Many thanks for any help with this.

**CODE**

```
<form method="get" action="/" id="languageSwitch">
        <fieldset>

            <select name='cat' id='cat' class='postform' >
                <option value='0' selected='selected'>Choose a country&#8230;</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="united-kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="us">US</option>
            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery('#cat').change(function(){
                    jQuery('#cat').change(function() {
                      jQuery("#statecat").toggle(jQuery(this).val() == "us");
                    });

                    if(jQuery('#cat').val()=="0")
                    jQuery('form#languageSwitch').siblings('div').show();
                        else{
                        jQuery('form').siblings('div').hide();
                        jQuery('.'+jQuery('#cat').val()).show();

                        }
                    });
            </script> 

        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form method="get" action="/" id="stateSwitch">
        <fieldset>

            <select name='statecat' id='statecat' class='postform' >
                <option value='0' selected='selected'>Choose a state&#8230;</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="ak">Alaska</option>
                <option class="level-0" value="wy">Wyoming</option>
            </select>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery('#statecat').change(function(){
                    jQuery('.state1').each(function(){jQuery(this).hide(); });
                    if(jQuery('#statecat').val()=="ak")
                        jQuery('.ak').show();
                });
            </script> 

        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div class="united-kingdom">
        <h2>United Kingdom</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="us">
        <h2>US</h2>
        <div class="ak state1">
            <h2>Alaska</h2><ul>                  
            <li class="animal-listing" id="post-123">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/company/kiwi-kompany/">Alaska Test</a><br />
                Address:<br />Address<br />
                Country: Alaska<br />
                URL: http://www.somesite.co.nz<br />
                Telephone: 01902<br />
                Fax: 01293
            </li>
        </div>

        <div class="wy state1">
            <h2>Wyoming</h2>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem of the 'state' dropdown not appearing on the first selection was because for some reason you had nested `change()` handlers, so that event wasn't fired until the second selection was made.

Secondly, you can shorten your code by concatenating the selector for the display div of the state chosen from the value of the dropdown like this:

```
$('.' + $('#statecat').val()).show();
```

I also included some improvements to your code, such as removing unnecessary loops and caching selectors:

```
$('#cat').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#statecat").toggle(val == "us");

    if (val == "0") 
        $('#languageSwitch').siblings('div').show();
    else {
        $('form').siblings('div').hide();
        $('.' + val).show();
    }
});

$('#statecat').change(function() {
    $('.state1').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/665yvqec/3/)

Comment: Wow, where have you been all my life?? :-D
That worked beautifully, Rory!! Final bug, any ideas why when I go from `Alaska` back to `Choose a State...` that the results for `US` disappear? I've tried it on your jsfiddle and the problem still remains. Help?

Comment: That's because the value for `Choose a state...` is `0`, and there is no `.0` div to show. That's surely correct behaviour though - if no state is selected, no state should be shown, right?

Comment: That's an interesting point. I've always just shown all by default. Is it possible to tweak my code to allow this to happen? Many thanks again.

Comment: If you want to show all states when `Choose...` is selected, you can use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/665yvqec/4/